# p5.js loadImage and image to set a background image

Tags: javascript, image, p5.js, loadimage

SOLVED
I was missing script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"> in index.html

I am using JavaScript and the p5.js library in VSC and trying to get an image to load to use as a background. Previously I had the script.js and background.png files in separate folders under the same parent directory, but I changed them temporarily to see if the file paths were the problem.
The code in script.js stands as following:

```
let BG;

function preload() {
    BG = loadImage('background.png');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
    image(BG,0,0,100,100);
}
```

And as mentioned before, the files are all in the same directory. [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdRj8.png)

I would like to get the image saved as background.png to display on the canvas because currently it does not. I have used loadImage() and image() in exactly this fashion before in preload() and setup(), though this time it is not working.
Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This should work. If you replace the image with `'http://placekitten.com/220/200'`, you'll see the image loads and draws fine. Are you running a localhost server in the directory, e.g. `python -m http.server`, then navigating to http://localhost:8000? If you are just clicking open the HTML file, I don't think the image resource will be requestable. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: I'm using a Liveserver extension on VSCode and it's starting at port 5500. I tried replacing the loadImage with that url and it hasn't loaded on my liveserver.

Comment: Are there errors in the console? Could you provide network request response code/details, please? Did you try running it "vanilla", without the VSCode setup, to see if that worked for you?

Comment: In the Chrome console after running with liveserver, there are no red messages. [link](https://imgur.com/a/f3PHl9T). Where can I find network request response details?

Comment: You can click the two arrows (>>) and click Network, then look for the image URL resource and see what the status is.